# Including and calling external php scripts from cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

On the server I had php scripts responsible for sending notifications to mobile phones. It runs well if the scripts are called from the same directory.

The problem is to call the scripts from cakePHP app.

I include the notifications script inside cakePHP function like this:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folder_name/Notifications.php';
```

When I call the script, I get the following warnings inside the scripts:

```
include_once(./db_connect.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [/home/username/public_html/gcm_server_php/db_functions.php

Warning (2): include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening './db_connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/username/public_html/cake-dev/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') [/home/username/public_html/gcm_server_php/db_functions.php, line 21]
```

And the following fatal error:

```
Error: Class 'DB_Connect' not found 
File: /home/username/public_html/gcm_server_php/db_functions.php    
Line: 25
```

Any help is much appreciated. Keep in mind that calling scripts from the same directory, everything runs smooth.

Comment: Looks pretty obvious - it can't open the file because the path assumes the cwd is the folder `folder_name`. Just edit the file so that `db_coǹnect.php` is included with an absolute path. Note that, unless there's some specific reason, that doesn't look like something which should be in your webroot at all - it should be in the vendor folder (i.e. http inaccessible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the include links were wrong throughout the application. What was needed to be done was including the other files with and absolute path like this:

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folder_name/Notifications.php';